# How to get the output of the neo4j query in currency format (With $ symbol)?

Tags: neo4j

For the following query (pseudo query)

```sql
MATCH (data:DATA { id: 123 })
WITH data
RETURN
  apoc.temporal.format(data.last_seen, "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss") AS last_seen,
  data.amount As amount
ORDER BY last_seen DESC;
```

I want output like:

```
last_seen: '08/31/2021 12:03:26'
amount: $12.00
```

`last_seen` is fine. But I didn't get a method to format the `amount` column.

Gone through https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/mathematical/number-conversions/

But I didn't find a way to ad `$` symbol at the beginning.

Comment: You can just concatenate `COALESCE('$' + data.amount)` [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce)

Comment: Thank you. @Lazar Đorđević

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you found apoc already:

COALESCE ( ‘$’+ apoc.number.format(data.amount, '#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)', 'it'), ‘no amount’)